# How to modify the columns

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Using the code below, I extract data from bq table and in that, I have done some data cleaning(updating null values)

```
    query3 ="""
UPDATE pvr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a t
SET t.movie_buff_uuid = u.movie_buff_uuid
FROM pvr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a u
WHERE t.movie_name=u.movie_name
;"""
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to approach this would be to load your dataset into a staging table into BigQuery using the `load_table_from_dataframe()` method.

example:

```
client.load_table_from_dataframe(dataframe=df1, destination='project_id.dataset_id.updated_dataset')
```

The result of the above will create a table in BigQuery with your the data from your dataframe which contains the updated ID values.

Once within BigQuery you can issue a update statement similar to this:

```
UPDATE project_id.dataset_id.testing_dataset t
SET t.id = u.id
FROM project_id.dataset_id.updated_dataset u
WHERE t.movie_name=u.movie_name
```

This will replace the IDs in your testing_dataset with all matches from staging table you updated the IDs on in python.

Once the data is updated you can drop the `updated_dataset` table.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more here i am confused with testing and updated dataset

Comment: I've updated with a little more detail.  But essentially you load your dataframe into BQ as a table, refer to it in an update statement, then you can drop the table loaded from the dataframe.

Comment: i am getting this error table_id must be a fully-qualified ID in standard SQL format, e.g., "project.dataset.table_id", got updated_dataset

Comment: i have modified the code as per your suggestion kindly check

Comment: the table names should be fully qualified, meaning project and dataset separated by a `.`.  See the updates above

Comment: sorry to bother you  but still i am getting the same error   table_id must be a fully-qualified ID in standard SQL format, e.g., "project.dataset.table_id", got ecr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a.updated_dataset   tableid = `ecr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a`

Comment: And  i have added a drop code kindly check

Comment: This does not look like a valid table id, you have one to many objects in there.  It seems you have a project, then dataset, then two other positions, should only be one. "pvr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a.updated_dataset"

"project_id.dataset_id.table"

Comment: this is the valid id ecr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a

Comment: @JerryVfc, the table id which you provided is `ecr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a.updated_dataset`  is not valid. Can you please try by removing `updated_dataset` from the table id in the code?

Comment: client.load_table_from_dataframe(dataframe=df1, destination='ecr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a')

query3 ="""
UPDATE pvr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a t
SET t.movie_buff_uuid = u.movie_buff_uuid
FROM ecr-data-project.testing_dataset.movie_metadata_v3a u
WHERE t.movie_name=u.movie_name;"""........ as you said @shipra sarkar i have removed updated

Comment: the values is updated but i am getting this error 400 UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

Comment: Hi @JerryVfc, this issue occurs when the BigQuery target table contains duplicate rows. If a row in the table to be updated joins with more than one row from the FROM clause, then BigQuery returns this error. To remove this error, you need to remove the duplicate rows from the destination table and then perform update operation.

Comment: to removing duplicate i thought to use drop function but both destination and From name or same so how to drop the old value in the table @Shipra Sarkar

Comment: The other option is if there is anything additional in the underlying table that defines uniqueness you could modify the where clause to reflect.  For example something like WHERE t.movie_name=u.movie_name and t.col_x = u.col_x etc...

Comment: @JerryVfc, is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes i have planned to remove all the additional values once the table is updated @Shipra

Comment: If this answer has resolved your issue, please consider marking correct and upvoting

Answer (score 0):

You may update rows in table using **UPDATE SQL** like this

```
UPDATE `testing_dataset` SET movie_name = xxx WHERE id = yyy
```

Check [Big Query DML Documenntation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) document here.

Comment: this is manual way where i can add data one by one what if i need to update 1000 of rows